# Constructing Turan Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A "Turan Graph " on $n$ vertices is graph on $n$ vertices without triangles and  with exactely $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor$ edges.

How many are the Turan Graphs on $8$ vertices? 
There's an easy way to construct them?

I'm looking for pictures of this graphs in the case $n=8$.

Comment: So you want graphs with $8$ vertices, $16$ edges, and no triangles. Have you drawn any such graph? Seen how the "no triangles"-limitation affects things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of vertices is even, say $2m$, we may label any vertex with an element of $\mathbb{Z}/(2m\mathbb{Z})$ and draw and edge between two vertices iff the difference between their labels lies in $\{1,3,5,\ldots,2m-1\}$. In such a way we have a $m$-regular graph with exactly $m^2$ edges and no triangle, essentially because the sum of three odd integers cannot be zero. If a Turan graph is also a difference graph, it has to have such a structure by [Freiman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiman%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Construct $K_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor, n - \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$, the complete bipartite graph in which we split the vertices in two sets, as evenly as possible. After a little calculations you should be able to get that the number of edges is $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor$, which is the maximum possible for a triagular-free graph by Turan's Theorem for $k=3$, where the a clique can have at most $k-1$ members.